# Is there a way to determine which files were indexed by the indexer in Azure Cognitive Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is there any way to determine the files that were indexed by the indexer? I see an API that returns the indexer history and the number of files that were indexed, but not the actual file names themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The content in your index represents the indexed files. You could simply search for * (wildcard) to list all files that were indexed.

Comment: well, to be more specific, I was trying to get all the file that were indexed by a particular run of the indexer.

Comment: Are you pushing content via the SDK or pulling data in with one of the built-in indexers? If you push content with the SDK you can add metadata to your items. I add metadata for all items I push, like a timestamp for when the item was pushed, name of the server pushing the item, etc.